# Wrong image url in Wordpress into the WooCommerce Gateway Stripe

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In a WordPress website, I am using the WooCommerce plugin and the WooCommerce Gateway Stripe.

Everything is working correctly except that the Google Chrome developer tells me that I have "Mixed Content" on 3 images:

- Mixed Content: The page at 'https://my-website.com/commande' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure element 'http://my-website/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-gateway-stripe/assets/images/visa.svg'.
- Mixed Content: The page at 'https://my-website.com/commande' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure element 'http://my-website.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-gateway-stripe/assets/images/amex.svg'.
- Mixed Content: The page at 'https://my-website.com/commande' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure element 'http://my-website.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-gateway-stripe/assets/images/mastercard.svg'.

I checked the source code of the plugin and the URLs of these images are built with the following code:

```
'visa' => '<img src="' . WC_STRIPE_PLUGIN_URL . '/assets/images/visa.svg" class="stripe-visa-icon stripe-icon" alt="Visa" />'
```

And, according to the plugin source code, the `WC_STRIPE_PLUGIN_URL` is built with the following code:

```
define( 'WC_STRIPE_PLUGIN_URL', untrailingslashit( plugins_url( basename( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) ), basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) );
```

So I guess that the issue is with the WordPress `plugins_url` method? According to the source code of WordPress, this method works with the constants `WPMU_PLUGIN_URL` and `WP_PLUGIN_URL`.

These constants are defined into the `default-constants.php` file. So I checked the source code:

```
if ( ! defined( 'WP_PLUGIN_URL' ) ) {
        define( 'WP_PLUGIN_URL', WP_CONTENT_URL . '/plugins' ); // Full URL, no trailing slash.
}
```

and the `WP_CONTENT_URL` is defined by the following source code:

```
if ( ! defined( 'WP_CONTENT_URL' ) ) {
        define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', get_option( 'siteurl' ) . '/wp-content' ); // Full URL - WP_CONTENT_DIR is defined further up.
}
```

So finally, I checked into my database and the "options" table. The "siteurl" field seems to be correct: `https://my-website.com`

If someone knows how to fix this issue!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fix the issue using the [Really Simple SSL plugin](https://really-simple-ssl.com/).

The plugin offers several options in order to automatically fix "Mixed Content" issues.